# Setup oracle 19 with docker conect with XID not service name

Tags: oracle, docker, docker-compose, oracle19c

Hi I have to migrate from oracle 12 to oracle 19, noting special. I use the following compose file

```
   oracle19:
    image: container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:latest
    container_name: oracle19
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ~/oradata:/opt/oracle/oradata 
      - ./oracle19/setup:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setup
      - ./oracle19/startup:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/startup
    ports:
      - 1521:1521
      - 1551:1521
      - 5500:5500
    environment:
      - ORACLE_PWD=test1234
      - ORACLE_PDB=XE
```

Container is running, but I was able to connect just using service name not XID:

`jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE` not like in the oracle 12 with **:**  for XID but for service with **/**

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
```

Where is my mistake or is it possible to use XID for connection in oracle 19c?

Comment: And what are SID and SERVICE_NAME for the PDB?

Comment: In my setup was just that, shown in the question. I tried with ORACLE_SID:  XE ,but does not work.

Comment: @Xelian Can you explain exactly why you need to connect to the SID instead of the service name? Understanding the underlying reason may help us identify a work around. For example, I once had a similar problem with 19c on Docker because our application was using an ancient IBM JDBC provider(?) that didn't support service names. We found a workaround, but I can't remember what it was.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a pdb then the pdb does not have a Sid but only a service name.
The container database has a sid but you cannot store user data in the container.

So it works as designed. With a pdb use service name and You are fine.
By the way, Oracle recommends using service names for client and application connections since 10g.

Comment: Can I remove this  ORACLE_PDB=XE and to created SID which to use for connection?
to replace with ORACLE_SID=XE ?

Comment: No, the preconfigured docker container will always create a pdb. 
If you don't want to use a pdb then you will have to use a different image or create your own docker image. 

However 19c is the last version supporting non-cdb databases. The next LTS Release 23c will only support container databases with pdb.